# ImageJ script: "This command requires a selection" when there is one

Tags: javascript, imagej

I am trying to write a script in javascript. It uses a plugin called `Radial Profile`, but I believe the problem is somewhere lese.

I have:

```
IJ.run("Select All", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Radial Profile", "x=524 y=524 radius=524");
```

but this yields the error `This command requires a selection` (while it runs fine if I use the menu from the point after the "Select all" step in the script).

I actually also get an error `This command requires a rectangular selection` if I use only built-in commands as:

```
IJ.run("Select All", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Make rectangular selection rounded", "");
```

What am I doing wrong? Shall I pass the selection to IJ.run in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `IJ.run(imp, "Make rectangular selection rounded", "");` tells me you are using [Fiji](http://fiji.sc), as this command is included in [Fiji_Plugins](https://github.com/fiji/Fiji_Plugins/tree/master/src/main/java/fiji/selection).

Are you sure your Fiji installation is up to date? (via *Help > Update Fiji*)

The following script works as expected (on the currently active imgae) when run from the script editor in an up-to-date Fiji installation:

```
importClass(Packages.ij.IJ);

imp = IJ.getImage();
IJ.run("Select All", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Make rectangular selection rounded", "radius=5");
```

If it does *not* work on your machine, please report a bug via *Help > Report a bug* in the menu. This allows the developers to know some (possibly important) details about your local installation.

Comment: Thanks for this, this made me realise that the problem was located in the way the image I treat is obtained. I'll post a new, different question.